# Logical Operator For Or

Tags: php

I am trying to do:

```
if(x != 1 || 2) echo 'okay';
```

With my code here:

```
if($_POST["timezone"] != ("Pacific/Midway" || "America/Adak" || "Etc/GMT+10" || "Pacific/Marquesas")) {
    $timezone_error = 'Invalid timezone';
}
```

Whereas I put in information that did not equal, and $timezone_error was still not set, what is the proper OR operator that I should be using, or is this possible at all?  I would rather not write $_POST['x'] != 1, $_POST['x'] != 2 all out separately as this is quite a long list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want is something like this

```
$array = array("Pacific/Midway" , "America/Adak" , "Etc/GMT+10" , "Pacific/Marquesas");

if (!in_array($_POST["timezone"], $array){
 $timezone_error = 'Invalid timezone';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct format would be:

```
if(x!= 1 || x!=2) echo 'okay';
```